# How to exit a loop

Tags: python, loops, break

I want to shorten the process time of my script, and in order to do that I need to know how I can exit a loop if some condition is met.

For instance I'm running through all my faces and if something is `True`, then it should stop the loop and not just 1 step:

```
for i in range(n_faces):
    if *something* is True:
        continue
```

I know that by doing this, I can skip just 1 step, but how do I skip the whole loop after `*something* is True`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `break` statement to break out from the loop, see the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

> 4.4. break and continue Statements, and else Clauses on Loops
>
> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the smallest enclosing for
>   or while loop.